# EC2/ECS Cross Account Serverless Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a problem deploying serverless service on EC2/ECS environment.

Since I am deploying on EC2/ECS environment, I need to use `credential_source` to access instance iam role. (No file on ~/.aws/credentials)

```
## ~/.aws/config
[profile dev]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/CrossAccount-AssumeJenkins
output = json
credential_source=EcsContainer #Ec2InstanceMetadata on EC2
region = ap-southeast-1
```

It's working on AWS cli.

```
aws s3 ls --profile dev #working
```

But when I try to deploy serverless, it's not working.

```
#load config from ~/.aws/config 
export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
sls deploy --stage dev --verbose

sls deploy --stage dev --verbose --aws-profile dev #also not working
```

Below is the error stack.

```
Error --------------------------------------------------

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ec2-user/.aws/credentials'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.readFileSync (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:95:26)
    at IniLoader.parseFile (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/shared-ini/ini-loader.js:6:47)
    at IniLoader.loadFrom (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/shared-ini/ini-loader.js:56:30)
    at Config.region (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/node_loader.js:100:36)
    at Config.set (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:507:39)
    at Config.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:342:12)
    at Config.each (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:507:32)
    at new Config (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:341:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/node_loader.js:110:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/aws.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/provider/awsProvider.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/index.js:24:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at PluginManager.loadAllPlugins (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:110:10)
    at pluginManager.loadConfigFile.then.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:96:35)
From previous event:
    at Serverless.init (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:94:8)
    at initializeErrorReporter.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js:74:8)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
From previous event:
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js:64:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)

Get Support --------------------------------------------
    Docs:          docs.serverless.com
    Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
    Issues:        forum.serverless.com

Your Environment Information ---------------------------
    Operating System:          linux
    Node Version:              10.18.1
    Framework Version:         1.62.0
    Plugin Version:            3.3.0
    SDK Version:               2.3.0
    Components Core Version:   1.1.2
    Components CLI Version:    1.4.0
```

After touching ~/.aws/credentials, below is the new error.

```
## ~/.aws/credentials
[default]

#no entry
```

Here is the error stack.

```
Error --------------------------------------------------

Error: Profile dev does not exist
    at Object.addProfileCredentials (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/provider/awsProvider.js:100:15)
    at AwsProvider.getCredentials (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/provider/awsProvider.js:374:12)
    at AwsProvider.request (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/provider/awsProvider.js:226:48)
    at Variables.getValueFromCf (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:756:8)
    at Variables.getValueFromSource (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:567:17)
    at Variables.splitAndGet (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:436:17)
    at _.map.match (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:373:41)
    at arrayMap (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:639:23)
    at Function.map (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9554:14)
    at Variables.populateMatches (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:373:14)
    at Variables.populateValue (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:404:30)
    at _.map.variable (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:286:12)
    at arrayMap (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:639:23)
    at Function.map (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9554:14)
    at Variables.populateVariables (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:285:14)
    at Variables.populateObjectImpl (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:318:30)
    at prepopulateService.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:199:16)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
From previous event:
    at initialCall (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:198:10)
    at Variables.initialCall (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:102:12)
    at Variables.populateService (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:196:17)
    at Serverless.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:120:27)
    at serverless.init.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js:75:30)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:136:16
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:57:14
    at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)
From previous event:
    at initializeErrorReporter.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js:75:8)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
From previous event:
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js:64:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)

Get Support --------------------------------------------
    Docs:          docs.serverless.com
    Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
    Issues:        forum.serverless.com

Your Environment Information ---------------------------
    Operating System:          linux
    Node Version:              10.18.1
    Framework Version:         1.62.0
    Plugin Version:            3.3.0
    SDK Version:               2.3.0
    Components Core Version:   1.1.2
    Components CLI Version:    1.4.0
```

Comment: so you have `/home/ec2-user/.aws/credentials` file with `[dev]` section defined ?

Comment: none. I have `~/.aws/credentials` file with no entry. I only need the `~/.aws/config` for switching role with `credential_source=EcsContainer`. Do I need to add `[dev]` profile on `credentials`? Thank you

Comment: As far as I remember nodejs uses `credentials` file by default (it can be changed) while awscli (written in python uses config by default)

Comment: It appears that aws js sdk doesn't support `credential_source`. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1916 and `export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1` doesn't work on my case.